# What type of deliverables are expected of me in my new job?

Tags: process, deliverables

On a phone screening today, I was asked what kind of deliverables do I turn in to programmers? I know my answer could have been better but I am actually not sure if I answered correctly since I've only once worked with a programmer and turned in sketch files.

So, what kind of deliverables should I talk about once this question comes up again?

Comment: What is the job title/position description??? A pretty important piece of information if you want a sensible answer.

Comment: This is rather broad and specific to you. What I turn in is not what you turn in. You should not be describing what **your** deliverables are based on other's input. As long as you answered the question honestly, you answered it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, if your role is that of a UX Designer then anything helping the developers understand the critical requirements, users and preliminary design work could be of benefit.  The potential list of materials that theoretically could be provided is quite large, you wouldn't normally do all of these activities but here are some:

- business case documents (may have been done by others for you)
- use cases
- user research summaries
- user stories
- personas
- “day in the life” scenario
- storyboard
- journey maps
- user flow maps,identifying “red routes”; the most important pathways
- information architecture
- wireframes
- mockups
- low and/or high fidelity prototypes

UI folks would provide them with things that are built on the UX work like

- visual designs
- interaction designs
- (there's probably more here in the UI basket that I'm not aware of that would be helpful as well)

Bottom line, I think any material that helps show the research, analysis and reasoning behind the wireframes or prototypes you are providing them is useful but the developers should be included and aware of the preliminary UX work all through the process, not just have stuff thrown "over the wall" at them when it comes times to start formal coding/development.

Comment: one more thing UX designers has to interact with developer as well as testers to check that functionality won't be change.